# Вложенность в Sass

Tags: css, sass

Есть код .sass, без фигурных скобок **{}**

```
.header
  display:flex
  justify-content:space-between
.nav
  display:flex
  flex-direction:column
  align-items:center
  justify-content: space-between
```

как сделать вложенность не используя {} чтобы она работала ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для вложенности используйте знак амперсанда & 
Для SCSS:

```
.header {
    display:flex
    justify-content:space-between
     & .nav {
      display:flex
      flex-direction:column
      align-items:center
      justify-content: space-between
      }
    }
```

Для SASS:

```
.header
  display: flex
  justify-content:space-between
  & .nav
    display:flex
    flex-direction:column
    align-items:center
    justify-content: space-between
```

Comment: Короткая статья по использованию вложенности - http://itscreen.tk/blog/20-uproshaem-sass-ispolzuya-ampersand/

Comment: Ну это понятно, а без {} фигурных скобок можно обойтись?

Comment: Обновлено решение для sass синтаксиса

Comment: Спасибо!Я уже хотел сам ответить на свой вопрос, но увидел ваш ответ для SASS!